# Verlinde formula requires compact Riemann surface

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topology, chern-simons-theory

Assume a Chern-Simons theory on a 3-mfld of the form $\Sigma_g \times S^1$, where $\Sigma_g$ is a Riemann surface of genus $g$. In his paper, Witten shows that one can use the Verlinde formula to get the dimension of the Hilbert space associated to $\Sigma_g$, which equals the partition function of the theory. Furthermore, this formula only depends on $g$ and the Chern-Simons level $k$.

My question is, what are the requirements on $\Sigma_g$? Is it really **any** Riemann surface, or does it need to be compact? Witten does not mention anything about this, but neither does he mention what kinds of manifolds one can get from surgery on $S^3$, so I am not sure.